# jQuery Plugin Authoring: How do can I get my plugin to operate on multiple sets of values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery plugin:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.test = function(selector){
        $this = this;

                $(selector).bind("click", function(){
                    methods.showvalue($this);
                });
    };
    var methods = { 
        showvalue   :   function($this){
            var output = "";
            $this.each(function(i,e){
                output += $(e).val();
            })
            alert(output);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

With this markup:

```
<form>
    <p>
        First section<br />
        <input type="text" class="test" name="firstValue" value="one" />
        <input type="text" class="test" name="secondValue" value="two" />
        <input type="text" class="test" name="thirdValue" value="three" />
        <button type="button" id="button1">push</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        Second section<br />
        <input type="text" class="test2" name="firstValue2" value="1" />
        <input type="text" class="test2" name="secondValue2" value="2" />
        <input type="text" class="test2" name="thirdValue2" value="3" />
        <button type="button" id="button2">push</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

and this initializer:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // first section
        $(".test").test("#button1");

        // second section
        $(".test2").test("#button2");
    });
```

Regardless of which button I push I always get a string with "123" in it. My goal is to get "123" when the second button gets pressed, and "onetwothree" one the first button is pressed.

What am I missing? Why isn't it behaving that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare

```
var $this = this;
```

Otherwise, $this gets attached to the window and becomes global.

Also,  you might want this instead, so you don't attach several callbacks:

```
$.fn.test = function(selector){
    var $this = this;
    $(selector).bind("click", function(){
       methods.showvalue($this);
    });
    return this;
};
```

EDIT: Demo http://jsfiddle.net/VSDLJ/

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer the object in the each loop:

```
return this.each(function() {  
   obj = $(this);  
});
```

Or in your case:

```
return this.each(function() {  
  $this = $(this);
  $(selector).bind("click", function(){
    methods.showvalue($this);
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, no. That just alerts "3"